# LitElement initialize State from Properties without default value

Tags: lit-element

I'm trying out Lit and I'm having trouble figuring out how to initialize a state field from props. Here's a basic contrived pagination component:

```js
export class Pagination extends BaseElement {
  static styles = [BaseElement.styles];

  @property({type: Number})
  selected = 0;

  @state()
  _selected = this.selected;

  @property({type: Number})
  total!: number;

  @property({type: Number})
  pageSize: number = 10;

  @state()
  _numPages = Math.ceil(this.total / this.pageSize);

  render() {
    const numPages = Math.ceil(this.total / this.pageSize);

    console.log(numPages, this._numPages, this._selected);

    return html`
      <ul class="pagination">
        <li><a href="#" rel="prev">${msg("Previous", {id: 'pagination.previous', desc: 'Previous button in pagination'})}</a></li>
        ${Array.from(Array(_numPages).keys()).map((e, i) => html`<li class=${this._selected === i ? "active" : ""}><a href="#">${i + 1}</a></li>`)}
        <li><a href="#" rel="next">${msg("Next", {id: 'pagination.next', desc: 'Previous button in pagination'})}</a></li>
      </ul>
    `;
  }
}
```

This fails in render when using `this._numPages` (throws RangeError for the map because it's `NaN`), but is fine with `numPages`. It seems like if the state is using public properties that have defaults, it works, but otherwise it fails. I think this has to do with the fact that when the element is created it doesn't have props yet, so the initial first render doesn't have a value. But what is the right pattern to achieve this then in that case? The documentation here says "In some cases, internal reactive state may be initialized from public properties—for example, if there is a expensive transformation between the user-visible property and the internal state." (https://lit.dev/docs/components/properties/#public-properties-and-internal-state).

For completeness, here's a snippet of output of tsc:

```js
import { __decorate } from "tslib";
import { html } from 'lit';
import { localized, msg } from '@lit/localize';
import { property } from 'lit/decorators/property.js';
import { state } from 'lit/decorators/state.js';
import { BaseElement } from '../BaseElement.js';
let Pagination = class Pagination extends BaseElement {
    constructor() {
        super(...arguments);
        this.selected = 0;
        this._selected = this.selected;
        this.pageSize = 10;
        this._numPages = Math.ceil(this.total / this.pageSize);
    }
    render() {
        const numPages = Math.ceil(this.total / this.pageSize);
        console.log(this._selected, this._numPages);
        return html `
      <ul class="pagination">
        <li><a href="#" rel="prev">${msg("Previous", { id: 'pagination.previous', desc: 'Previous button in pagination' })}</a></li>
        ${Array.from(Array(numPages).keys()).map((e, i) => html `<li class=${this.selected === i ? "active" : ""}><a href="#">${i + 1}</a></li>`)}
        <li><a href="#" rel="next">${msg("Next", { id: 'pagination.next', desc: 'Previous button in pagination' })}</a></li>
      </ul>
    `;
    }
};
Pagination.styles = [BaseElement.styles];
__decorate([
    property({ type: Number })
], Pagination.prototype, "selected", void 0);
__decorate([
    state()
], Pagination.prototype, "_selected", void 0);
__decorate([
    property({ type: Number })
], Pagination.prototype, "total", void 0);
__decorate([
    property({ type: Number })
], Pagination.prototype, "pageSize", void 0);
__decorate([
    state()
], Pagination.prototype, "_numPages", void 0);
Pagination = __decorate([
    localized()
], Pagination);
export { Pagination };
```

Comment: What do you mean by "fails in render"?

Comment: @abraham `this._numPages` is `NaN`, so it throws a RangeError

Answer (score 1):

The @property decorator only declares the property for any lit-element component. To initialize the property with an default value, you need to declare it in Constructor.

I am not clear on your issue, what i understand that _numPages is giving error. So you can declare and initialize it as follow.

Below is your modified code.

```html
export class Pagination extends BaseElement {
  static styles = [BaseElement.styles];

  @property({type: Number})
  selected = 0;

  @state()
  _selected = this.selected;

  @property({type: Number})
  total!: number;

  @property({type: Number})
  pageSize: number = 10;

  @property({type: Number})
  _numPages: number;
  
  constructor() {
    super();
    this._numPages = 10
  }

  @state()
  _numPages = Math.ceil(this.total / this.pageSize);

  render() {
    const numPages = Math.ceil(this.total / this.pageSize);

    console.log(numPages, this._numPages, this._selected);

    return html`
      <ul class="pagination">
        <li><a href="#" rel="prev">${msg("Previous", {id: 'pagination.previous', desc: 'Previous button in pagination'})}</a></li>
        ${Array.from(Array(_numPages).keys()).map((e, i) => html`<li class=${this._selected === i ? "active" : ""}><a href="#">${i + 1}</a></li>`)}
        <li><a href="#" rel="next">${msg("Next", {id: 'pagination.next', desc: 'Previous button in pagination'})}</a></li>
      </ul>
    `;
  }
}
```

Comment: I've updated the question to include the compiler output. You can see that the defaults in TS are included in the constructor of the JS. However, it seems you're right that when the component is instantiated there is no value in `this.total`. So I guess my question then is, what is the pattern to wait for a value that needs to come from props?

Comment: you could use Life-cycle methods for lit-elements. I am not sure of your use case but if you want a callback whenever a property is set/updated you can use "updated()" lifecycle method.

Comment: https://lit.dev/docs/components/lifecycle/ 
here you can get more details around life-cycle methods in lit-elements

Answer (score 0):

Assigning the values in the class fields feels risky. I would need to review this, but I *think* this will not use the instance values so it might have unintended side-effects. I would wait until the instance is available (like the constructor), but, setting it in the constructor is also too soon as the property does not yet have the value from the component, rather it has the initial value from the class-field.

So we need to delay this even further.

I've solved this by using the `firstUpdated` lifecycle hook:

```
@customElement("my-component")
export class MyComponent extends LitElement {

  @property()
  myProperty: string = "";

  @state()
  _internalState: string = "";

  override async firstUpdated() {
    // avoid unnecessary calls by waiting for any pending updated to complete.
    await this.updateComplete;
    this._internalState = this.myProperty;
  }

  ...
}
```